# Timer - Show a message after a specific time has passed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have got a timer on my form like and it shows the current time (based on my system) what i want to do is for example current time is "6:22 PM" so when it reaches "6:24 PM" it should show a Message as "You have to submit a report" how do i do? Here is my code.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
    }
```

This just shows the current time.Can someone help me on this "message box"?

Comment: what is time interval of timer1 ?

Answer (score 0):

what is time interval of timer1 ? Probably its 1000 ms i.e. 1 sec. Assuming 1 sec time interval, add a condition

```
private DateTime showOnDate = DateTime.Today;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 18 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 24 && showOnDate == DateTime.Today)
    {
        showOnDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        MessageBox.Show("You have to submit a report");
    }
}
```

Comment: it keeps spamming the messages how to stop it?

Comment: How about if i do it just once? not more than one

Comment: Why did we have to create a new method 'showOnDate' please explain

Comment: showOnDate is a variable and not a method. Its used to display only once per day, assuming the program is running 24/7 for multiple days. So daily when its 18:24 the and day is todays Date in the variable showOnDate, the condition in IF will be true, message box is shown. Also the showOnDate now assigned to next day date. Next time, the IF condition will not be true for today. It will be true on next day at 18:24. So no more spamming and also it shown once per day.

Comment: I get it now actually i am a beginner can u describe what's a variable and when do we need to create this variable?

Comment: @abdulwadood, Did your problem resolved by the solution provided by me? For understanding variables refer the link - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_variables.htm. For tutorial on C# refer the link - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/.

Comment: yes it worked but I did it in my own way it also worked using class.system string how to add the code in the comment section? I will show it to you.

Comment: Thanks for the  link @mukul I will look forward to it...is it necessary to learn C or C++ before jumping to C# because I directly jumped to c# without learning C or C++

Answer (score 0):

```
int minutes = Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/2017 06:24").Substract(Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2017 06:22")).TotalMinutes;

if(minutes >2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("2 minutes has expired);
}
```

Comment: Please describe how your answer solves the issue, don't just post code.