# c# How should I make my method run on time ticker

Tags: c#

This is just a simple problem that I wanted to solve for the sake of improving my skills. I want my method selectingtime to run and I also want the condition I put in the RunEvent to receive the value of string selecttime from selectingtime. If you did reply on this, I thank you so much.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int hourt;  
    int minutet;
    string hourformatt;
    string selectedtime;
    Timer tm = new Timer(); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tm.Interval = 1000; 
        tm.Tick += new EventHandler(RunEvent); 
        tm.Start();  
    }

    private void RunEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); 
        DateTime dateT = DateTime.Now; // created datetime

           if (dateT.ToString("hh:mm tt") == selectedtime) // condition where dateT.ToString is equal to selectedtime 
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Please work"); // expected output whenever dateT.ToString is equal to selected time.
           }                
    }

    private void selectingtime()
    {
        hourt = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); //textbox for hour
        minutet = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text); // textbox for minute
        hourformatt = textBox3.Text; // textbox for AM or PM
        selectedtime = hourt + ":" + minutet + " " + hourformatt; // example 05:31 PM
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {
        selectingtime();         
    }
```

Comment: err... what exactly is your question. Also, all that extra whitespace really makes your code hard to read

Comment: My question is how to make the private void selectingtime() to run in private void RunEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e). What seemed to be the problem sir?. I'm really sorry for those white spaces I used to space a lot lately when I was asked to Indent some of the statement before posting

Comment: Your question is unclear… if you want to run the method `selectingtime()` in the `RunEvent` method… simply call it as you are in the button click event. It may be beneficial to explain WHAT you are trying to accomplish as the posted code and your description of the problem does not really make much sense.

Comment: "if you want to run the method selectingtime() in the RunEvent method… " this is basically what I wanted to achieve. is it clear now? can you please point out what should I change or do by editing the post?

Comment: Then call it in the method... is that clear?

Comment: Replace the textbox to combobox, so no room for user to make any mistake. This will avoid conversion and user input validation. There is a logical problem in your code. Timer interval is 1 second. So, if the message box shown "Please work" and user clicks ok within seconds of appearing it, message box will be shown again. This will happen till the selected time is not passed. Add a class level boolean, so that it can restrict occurence to once. Refer the answer at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811160/timer-show-a-message-after-a-specific-time-has-passed/42811275#42811275".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void RunEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    selectingtime(); //This?
    label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); 

    DateTime dateT = DateTime.Now; // created datetime

   if (dateT.ToString("hh:mm tt") == selectedtime) // condition where dateT.ToString is equal to selectedtime 
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Please work"); // expected output whenever dateT.ToString is equal to selected time.
   }
}
```

Though, I suppose you may get an error on the INT32 converting when the texbox is null, empty, or has non-numerical characters. In that case, you may want to implement a try parse. Also, if you are stuck on the idea of "Getting" the select time from the method, then you need to have it return a string -- though this may meet your request, I don't think it is necessarily an "improvement".

P.S. You do not need to need to create a tick event with a new event handler instance, passed with the event method.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tm.Interval = 1000;
        tm.Tick += RunEvent;
        tm.Start();
    }

    private void RunEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedTime = selectingtime();
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        DateTime dateT = DateTime.Now; // created datetime

        if (dateT.ToString("hh:mm tt") == selectedTime) // condition where dateT.ToString is equal to selectedtime 
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Please work"); // expected output whenever dateT.ToString is equal to selected time.
        }
    }

    private string selectingtime()
    {
        DateTime time;
        string timeFormat = string.Format("{0}:{1} {2}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
        DateTime.TryParse(timeFormat, out time);
        return time.ToString("hh:mm tt");
    }
```

Comment: Sir Toskr, what about the button? I'm actually a beginner. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Well, if we are always checking the textbox values in the Tick event before we check the condition, then it seems we don't even really need the button anymore -- since the buttons task is already being fulfilled. If you want to keep the button for setting, then I would suggest sticking with what you had.

Comment: Thank you so much I'm gonna try this answer of yours after I'm done with my chores. your answer is really understandable for me.

Comment: It didn't run hehe. it says  var selectedTime = selectingtime(); "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable" and return time.ToString("hh:mm tt"); "since selectingtime() returns void; a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.

Comment: So change "void" to "string" in the method signature.